# How to render components in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js

I want to render component dependent on my variables
I use it :

`<div>{{ auth ? <AuthCorrect /> : <AuthIncorrect /> }}</div>`

but my app render like this :

{{ auth ?
auth correct
:
AuthIncorrect
}}

Someone know how to figure out this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conditional Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

```
<div v-if="auth">Authentication Successful</div>
<div v-else>Authentication Failed</div>
```